# Getting each echo in jQuery post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, apache, post

im using jquery post an php, and i need get each echo in the code php, someting else.

Jquery

```
.....jQuery.post("php/insert.php", {
    idu:idusr,
    fil:filtro,
}, function(data, textStatus){
    if(data == "error")
        alert("Error");         
    else
        alert(data);
});....
```

PHP

```
...for($i = 0; $i < $countUsuarios; $i++)
    {
        $por = porcentBar($countUsuarios, $i);
        echo $por."%|";

        insertEnviadoFidelizar($idcampana, $byUsuarios[$i]);
    }
    ...
    echo "error"
    ...
```

the problem is in each echo because it's view like 10%|20%|30% (together)
and i nedd see this separate

Comment: write echo $por."%| <br>";

Comment: how you want to see it separate ? you would like to see it in new line or would like to get every echo value one by one ?

Comment: In what way does it need to be separate? Separated by line breaks? Or receive them individually? Instead of echoing it as a string/html, you could return them as a `json_encode()` object, and then loop over them individually in javascript

Comment: quection is unclear, how do you want to separate it? and where do u want to sparate it?

Comment: @Sean Hi !! i need receive them individually, for example : 20%| and after 30%| , in consecuence i need this alert("20%|") , alert("30%|")

Comment: Hi @SupunFictionPraneeth !! i need receive them individually, for example : 20%| and after 30%| , in consecuence i need this alert("20%|") , alert("30%|")

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

PHP:

```
...for($i = 0; $i < $countUsuarios; $i++)
    {
        $por = porcentBar($countUsuarios, $i);
        echo $por."%|<|>";

        insertEnviadoFidelizar($idcampana, $byUsuarios[$i]);
    }
    ...
    echo "error"
    ...
```

JS:

```
.....jQuery.post("php/insert.php", {
    idu:idusr,
    fil:filtro,
}, function(data, textStatus){
    if(data == "error")
        alert("Error");         
    else{
        var splt_msg = data.split('<|>');
        $.each(splt_msg , function(index, value) { 
          alert(value); 
        });


    }

});....
```